# Katalon - How can I assign GlobalVariable to Test Case variable default value?

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio, katalon

When defining a Test Case variable with Katalon Studio, how can I set his default value to be a Global Variable value?

Answer (score 1):

So if you have `GlobalVariable.test` set to `"something"`, the following code will print "something" to console:

```
def a = GlobalVariable.test
println a
```